# confusion with the use of and operator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, operator-keyword

below is a simplified version of my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(5,2)),columns=['x','y'])
```

if both x and y values are > 5 then a new column 'z' will have a value of 0 else 1

```
df[z] = np.where(ddd.x>5 and ddd.y>5,0,1)
```

however, i get this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

get the same even if I use

```
df[z] = np.where(ddd.x>5 & ddd.y>5,0,1)
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Use brackets to separate the predicates: `np.where((ddd.x > 5) & (ddd.y > 5), 0, 1)`

Comment: what is the value  of variable z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parantheses for each condition otherwise it will not work:

```
df[z] = np.where((ddd.x > 5) & (ddd.y > 5), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add parenthesis for each condition. Check this out:

```
df[z] = np.where((ddd.x>5) & (ddd.y>5,0,1))
```